# How to handle server/timeout error on Mobile when using server/Laravel to change Firebase Database?

Tags: android, laravel, firebase, server, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

1. Mobile send request to server/Laravel.
2. And Server send request to Firebase DB and change some data from Firebase database.
3. The Firebase DB data is changed but
4. It sends the server/timeout/other error to mobile device.

How to handle these types of errors?

Comment: Please share error code or are you getting response in html form?

Comment: Just TimeOutError, **okey please look at this case..**
1. Android Device ------> server -------> firebase (Android device request the server to change the data of firebase)
2. Firebase Database Node changed by the server and send volley timeout error response on android device ..in some cases(like internet slow) .